# How do pointers to 2d arrays work in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

I'm pretty new to C++ and I've been playing around with the language to try to understand most of it.
I recently started to look into 2d arrays, and I totally understand arrays of pointers to arrays (created on the heap), but I have a harder time with the code below.

```cpp
int arr2d[3][2] = {
    {1, 2},
    {3, 4},
    {5, 6}
};
```

I understand that in memory, it acts as a single dimensional array, but I don't understand how pointers work with them. I tried assigning arr2d to an int pointer, but it doesn't work. So I tried with the auto keyword.

```cpp
int* a = arr2d; // throws an error
auto a = arr2d; // auto = int(*a)[2]
```

When hovering over "a" in Visual Studio, it gives me the type int(*a)[2]. This is what I really don't understand.

I have looked for documentation but I can't find this syntax anywhere. Can someone please explain to me what that pointer type does and how I can recreate it with any n-dimensional array?

Thank you!

Comment: n dimentional arrays are better implemented as 1D arrays (int*) or vector if you were to do them in c++. Then you do manual array indexing into the array, using multiplication. If this is what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: No, I'm just trying to learn how the language works. I know the best way to do arrays is to do 1d arrays but I'm just curious about what those pointers are.

Comment: You will need a pointer to a pointer of type int, like: int** a = arr2d; or like the code hovering which is a pointer to an array of type int holding 2 elements. a[0] as well as *a will access the first row and a[0][0] as well as *(*(a+0)+0) which is equivalent with **a will access the integer value of the first row and first column.

Comment: @ai2ys that will work in C only gcc gives warning for C++. I mean `int** a = arr2d;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is actually very interesting and, the more you learn about `C++` the more completely irrelevant you find it becomes in all but rare situations.

```
int arr2d[3][2] = {
    {1, 2},
    {3, 4},
    {5, 6}
};
```

So here you have an *identifier* `arr2d` and that *identifier* has a type:

*array of arrays*

Now the type *array* in `C++` relates to a contiguous block of objects. So you have a *contiguous block* of *contiguous blocks*.

However, when you use the identifier in an *expression* the rules of `C++` say it *decays* into a *pointer* to the first element of the array for which it is *type array* *(there is a subtle distinction between an array and a type called "array")*.

So when you do this:

```
auto a = arr2d;
```

Well the identifier `a` is now a *pointer* because `arr2d` has *decayed* into a pointer to the first element of the 2D Array you originally created. But what is the type of the pointer?

It is a *pointer* to the first element of an *array of arrays*. But the first element of an *array of arrays* is an *array* - so it is a *pointer to an array*. How is that written in `C++` syntax?

Like this:

```
int (*)[2]; // see the right-left-rule
```

`C++` syntax can be a dark art and none of it quite so dark as the declaration of types. The complexity of it is hidden for simple situations like an `int` but shows its metal when things get complicated.

```
int (*)[2]; // see the right-left-rule
```

This means a pointer (now go right) to an array of 2 elements (now go left) of type `int`.

`C++` types are declared onion like, unwrapping right to left to allow a unified syntax capable of declaring *anything* from an `int` to a function returning a function pointer to a function that returned a pointer to an array of function pointers... etc.

See: [right-left-rule](http://jdurrett.ba.ttu.edu/3345/handouts/RL-rule.html).

Incidentally you could avoid decaying to a *pointer to array* by using this syntax:

```
auto a = &arr2d; // get the address of the whole 2D array
```

Your `IDE` should show something like:

```
int (*)[3][2]; // pointer to array-of-array-of-int
```

You would access it like this:

```
(*a)[0][0] = 1; // dereference pointer to access 2D array it points to
```

But I suspect a better remedy to your problem is to use `std::array`. That will behave more predictably.

```
std::array<std::array<int, 2>, 3> arr2d = {{
    {1, 2},
    {3, 4},
    {5, 6}
}};

auto a = &arr2d;
```

Now `a` is type `std::array<std::array<int, 2>, 3>*`